# Converting bigint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert this bigint for Ex: 637194307500000000 using Microsoft sql server. I have tried

```
SELECT DATEADD(S, 637194307500000000, '19700101')
```

I am getting arithmetic overflow error.

Comment: Is that really seconds value `637194307500000000` ?

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: If that massive number is a fixed value, the best way would be to convert it to minutes/hours/days/years/eons

Comment: If that is seconds, the result will be year 20 205 300 914...

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server cannot represent a time that large.  If, perhaps you mean 6,371,943,075 seconds, then you could switch to minutes instead:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 6371943075 / 60, '19700101')
```

This produces the result `2171-12-02 08:11:00.000`, which itself seems a bit unlikely.